# Wpf create window lock

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I the following code that creates windows in an mdi form. The idea is to create a window of a certain type if it dosent exist, or bring it to front if there is already an instance.

```
  public static object CreateWindow(Type windowType, params object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_definitionToWindow)
            {
                var def = new WindowDefinition {ControlType = windowType, Args = args};

                System.Windows.Forms.Form win = null;
                if (_definitionToWindow.TryGetValue(def, out win))
                {                      
                    win.Activate();
                    return win;
                }      

                System.Windows.Controls.Control uiElement =
                    (System.Windows.Controls.Control) Activator.CreateInstance(windowType, args);


                object result = null;
                if (uiElement is Window)
                    result = WpfMdiHelper.ShowWpfWindowInMdi((Window) uiElement);
                else
                    result = WpfMdiHelper.ShowWpfControlInMdi((System.Windows.Controls.Control) uiElement);

                if (result is System.Windows.Forms.Form)
                {                       
                    _definitionToWindow.Add(def, result as System.Windows.Forms.Form);
                    lock (_windowslock)
                    {
                        _windows.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Form) result, uiElement as IHasViewModel);                           
                    }
                    ((System.Windows.Forms.Form) result).Disposed += new EventHandler(WindowsFactory_Disposed);
                }                
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteError("Window creation exception", ex.ToString(), LogEntryCodes.UIException);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code more or less works, but when you click a button that opens a window several types in quick succession it opens up several windows.

After running debug traces I found that `lock (_definitionToWindow)` is being bypassed by all the clicks (it looks like all calls are being made on the same thread) and the method blocks on `Activator.CreateInstance`. So when the 2nd call arrives to the dictionary check it doesn't find any previous instances and proceeds to recreate the window.

Anyone knows why this happens? and the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: To give a bit more information, it looks like it's the same thread (which explains why the lock isn't working) by wtf is the same thread doing in that code twice?

Comment: Using *lock* on an STA thread is illegal.  The CLR compensates for it by pumping a message loop.  Which will cause re-entrant execution of any event triggered by a Windows message, like a click.  Only ever run UI related code on the UI thread, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() where necessary.  So you'll never need to use *lock*.

Comment: Thanks for that info, most of the windows programming I've done has been in ASP.NET so I did not know that. In this case it is really UI related code running in the thread, it's creating and returning a Form, but point otherwise taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you a thread safe lock that only allows one caller into CreateWindowImpl even if they're on the same thread.  It doesn't block any threads though unlike lock().

```
static long Locked = 0;

static void CreateWindow(...)
{
   if(0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref Locked, 1))
   {
      try
      {
         CreateWindowImpl(...);
      }
      finally 
      {
         Interlocked.Exchange(ref Locked, 0);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that will definitely fix it, but how is the same thread in there twice?

Comment: I imagine Activator.CreateInstance is allowing events to be dispatched so CreateWindow is being re-entered.  All that's needed is a simple boolean flag (with no thread safety) probably.

Comment: At the very bottom of this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx is a note "The task for WPF is to avoid unexpected reentrancy without reintroducing the memory leak, which is why we don’t block reentrancy everywhere."